# Defining pure function using module

Tags: scoping, pure-function

I am creating a function `fun` which takes a parameter `p` and returns a pure function:

```
ClearAll[fun];
fun[p_] :=
 Module[{f, x0},
  f = 1 + #^2 &;
  x0 = p;
  f[#]/f[x0] &]
```

But the resulting `fun` seems to preserve some scoping stuff; for example

```
fun[0]
(* f$317[#1] / f$317[x0$317] & *)
```

instead of returning `1 + #1^2 &` as expected. On the other hand, passing an argument to the pure function makes it work normally:

```
fun[0][x]
fun[1][x]
(* 1 + x^2 *)
(* (1 + x^2) / 2 *)
```

How can I make `fun[0]` return `1 + #1^2 &`?

(The reason I use `Module[{f,x0},`...`]` is because I want to obtain `x0` from solving an equation involving `f'` and `p`, but that is unrelated to the scoping problem, which occurs even for the simple assignment `x0 = p`.)

Comment: `fun[p_] := Module[{f, x0}, f = 1 + #^2 &;
  x0 = p;
  Evaluate[ f[#]/f[x0] ] &]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comment by Jason B: `Evaluate` the body.

```
fun[p_] :=
 Module[{f, x0},
  f = 1 + #^2 &;
  x0 = p;
  Evaluate[ f[#]/f[x0] ] &
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue here is `Function` has attribute `HoldAll` so you need to break it through in this case. Jason B has shown one solution in the comment, another possible way is to make use of `Apply`:

```
ClearAll[fun];
fun[p_] := Module[{f, x0}, f = 1 + #^2 &;
  x0 = p;
  Function @@ {f[#]/f[x0]}]

fun[0]
```

Comment: How would this work with named formal parameters instead of slots? e.g. `Function[x, 2x]`. For example, `Module[{expr}, expr = 2 x; Function[x, Evaluate[expr]]]` does not work and the resulting function always returns `2x` as an expression rather than double the input

Comment: @goweon I guess you've commented in the wrong place? `Apply` is free of this issue: `Module[{expr}, expr = 2 x; Function @@ {x, expr}]` Another possible solution is: `Module[{expr}, expr = 2 x; Function[x, #] &@expr]`